# Best way to query the log files, with Spark or caseesndra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, hdfs

I have log files in different servers(5 servers connect through LAN) and I need to process and get the result

- Each node has 4TB log files and I'm using HDFS to load all log files into Spark
- Every time, when request come, the Spark load all files (5 * 4TB) then query with Spark SQL

What if I load all the log files into caseesndra and then query (it can be preloaded ) ? which is the fast way ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HDFS** and **Cassandra** has each their own advantages.

If you need to process **all** log files entirely, **HDFS** is a better choice because it is a **file system** and has been designed to store a massive amount of data and process them by batch.

Now, if you only need to process a **portion** of the log files, a **datastore** like **Cassandra** is a better choice because you can filter data by primary key and have faster access and skip scanning through all the files.

**Cassandra** is designed for OLTP workload whereas **HDFS** and the kind are designed for **OLAP** workload

Comment: Thanks for your detail reply, HDFS is the better choice to me according to you answer.